# Unzip Code PHP error

Tags: php, unzip

I have these lines of code to upload then unzip the file. It can successfully upload the file, but it cannot unzip it. I am doing this in the localhost in the meantime. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks. I have the folders `ZipFiles` and `UnzipFiles`.

```
//Upload the file
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $file_path = "ZipFiles/";
    $name       = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];  
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];  
    $file_path  = $file_path . basename($name);
    $files      = pathinfo($file_path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file_type  = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];

    $today = date("Y-n-j");  

    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $x = $zip->open($file_path);
        if ($x === true) {
            $zip->extractTo("UnzipFiles/"); 
            $zip->close();
            }
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you include the library of unzipping? what is this library?

Comment: Have you checked some error?

Comment: @YazanWYusuf, Sir I'm using `ZipArchive()`

Comment: I just created an if else condition, in the else i put `else { echo "failed";}` and that's what it shows, :(

Comment: So the problem is not the unzip, it is `move_uploaded_file()`: you don't have right permissions or your path doesn't exists. Generally, is better using absolute paths.

Comment: I added an else condition in the `unzip code`, that's where it failed, not on the `move_uploaded_files()`

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works.

Do you have permissions read / write in two folders?

Comment: Also, I'm testing this in a pc and a laptop, both are not working O_O

Comment: What is the version of PHP?